# PyCharm warns about unresolved reference of Django's model properties

Tags: python, django, pycharm

I'm following Django tutorial. When I use references to model objects, PyCharm highlights them with yellow and warns about "Unresolved reference". But my code is okay - it's run properly on Django's test webserver. Did you occur similar problem?

Let me show you some code snippet:

```
from django.db import models

class Task(models.Model):
    description = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    repeatable = models.BooleanField()
    activationDate = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.description
```

The code above defines class of Task model. Now, when I refer some properties in another Python module, some of references are yellow:

*views.py*

```
from .models import Task
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, render
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.template import loader
from django.urls import reverse
from django.views import generic

class IndexView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'app/index.html'
    context_object_name = 'tasks'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Task.objects.all() # I'm getting warning on 'objects'
```

In this example, PyCharm highlights 'objects' property and warn about "Unresolved reference 'objects' for class Task".

Do you know how to solve it?

Answer (score 3):

You will need to configure Pycharm so that it will understand it's a Django project.
You can do it in

**Preferences > Languages and Frameworks > Django > Enable Django support**

Also, indicate to Pycharm where to look for Environment packages in:

**Preferences > Project > Project Interpreter**